# How to match a list of string with substring using contains in karate

Tags: regex, karate

```
* def response = ["-1302.3000","110992.2204","-3990.6580","-7678.6279","4964.0000","3415.6366"]
* def val = '-1302.3'
Then match response contains "#regex ." + val + ".*"
```

Error:-
match failed: CONTAINS
$ | not a string (LIST:STRING)
["-1302.3000","110992.2204","-3990.6580","-7678.6279","4964.0000","3415.6366"]
'#regex .-1302.3.*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on the latest version of Karate (1.1.0)

```
* def response = ["-1302.3000","110992.2204","-3990.6580","-7678.6279","4964.0000","3415.6366"]
* def val = '-1302.3'
* match response contains "#regex " + val + ".*"
```

That said, see this suggestion below:

```
* def response = ["-1302.3000","110992.2204","-3990.6580","-7678.6279","4964.0000","3415.6366"]
* def numbers = response.map(x => x * 1)
* match numbers contains -1302.3
```

I leave it as a homework for you to understand how that works.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and I was using karate 1.0.1 version and I have just updated the version and now it is working fine though it was not version issue I believe but anyway its working now. And yes your 2nd solution is laos good that we can extract all the values and convert those into numbers by multyplying 1 using lambda expression of js and then we can compare witht he actual value. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Also I would like to learn if we have xpath filter like we have jsonpath filter? I have a scenario where I want to extract a block of xml using some filter and then want to do assertions on it. And this xml block will be dynamic and there is no certain sequence of that so we can extract the whole chunk from the response based on some filter value and then can do assertions easily .